# How do I avoid a segfault?

Tags: c, operating-system, gnu

I am using a GNU GCC Compiler with absolutely no library at all, using macOS 
Here is my code:

```c
#define in(port, to) __asm__ volatile ("inb %1, %0" : "=a" (to) : "Nd" (port))

char key() {
 char c;
 in(0x60, c);
 return c;
}
```

Calling this functions results in a segfault, suspecting the in() function in the preprocessor how do I avoid this?

Comment: You probably simply don't have permission to use this instruction. Reading ports of the CPU definitively sounds like the kind of thing the underlying OS will reserve to itself. It's like trying direct memory access, or interact directly with hardware peripherals. You just can't do it. Not unless you're the OS.